# Is it possible to use C# Initialization Syntax to pass a parameter?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In C#, using the initialization syntax I can say:

```
string[] mystrings = {"one", "two", "three"};
```

Is it possible to use the same array initialization syntax to convert this:

```
string test = "This is a good sentance to split, it has at least one split word to split on.";
string[] mystrings = test.Split(new string[] { "split" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Into something like this:

```
string test = "This is a good sentance to split, it has at least one split word to split on.";
string[] mystrings = test.Split({ "split" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

It seems like it should work but I can't get it to do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost there:

```
string[] mystrings = test.Split(new[]{ "split" }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Yeah, a `string` less to type :-)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need a new `string` method:

```
public static class StringExtensions {
  public static string[] Split(this string self, string separator, StringSplitOptions options) {
    return self.Split(new[] { separator }, options);
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
string[] mystrings = test.Split("split", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Now, it's up to you to decide if it's worth or not to introduce it.

For multiple separators, you can fix the `options` parameter (or put it in front, which will feel unnatural based on the other "overloads"):

```
public static class StringExtensions {
  // maybe just call it Split
  public static string[] SplitAndRemoveEmptyEntries(this string self, params string[] separators) {
    return self.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  }
}
```

And the usage:

```
string[] mystrings = test.SplitAndRemoveEmptyEntries("banana", "split");
```

Comment: cleaver, although if you still wanted to have multiple split strings then you would be in the same boat.

Comment: This is my preferred method. I almost always make an extension method similar to this, and even use optional parameters for the StringSplitOptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly have this syntax:

```
string test = "This is a good sentance to split, it has at least one split word to split on.";
string[] mystrings = test.Split(new[] { "split" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

but I am not sure if you can simplify it any further...

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extension method:

```
    public static String[] Split(this string myString, string mySeperator, StringSplitOptions options)
    {
        return myString.Split(new[] {mySeperator}, options);
    }
```

Then you can do:

```
    string test = "This is a good sentance to split, it has at least one split word to split on.";
    string[] mystrings = test.Split("split", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```